# Only allow ajax request to fire once (like button)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a button that on click adds 1 to a table value in my database (i.e a like button).

`When the user clicks the button:`

```
  var button_id = $(e.target).closest('div').attr('id');
  var id = button_id.substring(12);
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'update_like.php',
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(){
     //
    },
    error: function(){
      //
    }
  })
```

`update_like.php`

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);

if (!empty($_POST)){
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

**Q: What way can it check if they already liked it, so that they can only like the post once?**

I just thought of something like this:

Have a column called "likers" or something similar, with a long list of user IDs who've liked the post.

i.e.

`5 217 16 31893 ...` <-- user IDs

In `update_like.php`, check if the user who's logged in's ID can be found within that string. Something like:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT likers FROM posts WHERE id='$id'");
$likers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_id = $_SESSION['id']; // user ID

if (!empty($_POST)){
    if (!(preg_match("/\b$user_id\b/", $likers))){
        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$id'");
    }
}
```

Is this feasible?

Comment: You did not show the click event. But also consider instead of `$("#button").on("click"` do a `$("#button").one("click"`  it only fires once - see [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: @mplungjan It might be possible that due to error if it was not updated then you won't be able to click it again. Right?

Comment: Can't they just refresh the page and then they can click it again if you use `.one`?

Comment: You should disable or hide like button aswell if user has liked it

Comment: Sure that is possible. So all process should be on the server and the callback should remove the handler.

Comment: So in my `users` table, I could have a column for each user called `liked_posts` with a list of the post IDs, and on page load, if they have liked that post, show the button as different (liked)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var button_id = $(e.target).closest('div').attr('id');
var id = button_id.substring(12);
var idArray = [];
if (idArray.indexOf(id) === -1) {
 ajaxCall = $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'update_like.php',
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(){
     //
      idArray.push(id);
    },
    error: function(){
      //
    }
  });
}
```

On server side you can try this:
Assuming ID to be a comma separated list.

```
UPDATE posts 
SET likes = likes+1 
WHERE id = '$id'
AND FIND_IN_SET('$id', listofuserid) = 0
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for the client to edit this themselves / disable it so they can keep pressing the like button? Shouldn't it be server side?

Comment: @frosty Oh ! Your concern is if the user refresh the page then what happens? Why don't you check on page load that if a post has been liked by a user and if yes then don't show like button. Or try the above query for updating.